# After Big Sur 11.1 replaced beta, No Safari available

Tags: safari, beta

No problem converting from Beta to Big Sur 11.1non 2016 MacBook 12 except for Safari. The beta Safari remains, is not compatible, and I haven’t been able to locate installer for the right Safari.

This is a new/clean install so there is no backup as none needed. How to remove the beta?

Chrome is installed and apparently healthy

Thank you.
C

Answer (score 1):

You should re-install macOS 11.1 using the installer found in the App Store. This should restore all system components:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/macos-big-sur/id1526878132?mt=12

Comment: That is what I did. Beta Safari remains, neutralized as incompatible. Where did public Safari go? It is integrated into the os package but invisible

Comment: Safari is handled differently from the rest of the system - since it receives updates independently. This is why your attempt to perform an unsupported restore caused problems. You could try erasing Safari completely or installing a Safari beta. However, the simple fact is that performing a version revert in this nature is completely unsupported and recommended against.

Comment: If you didn't have a backup, you should wipe your computer and re-install the public release which will restore Safari.

Comment: Ezekiel could you clarify and point me to a source to explain the supported path from beta to public? I believe it was in the Apple user boards where the advice I followed was given re proper path from beta to 11.1 was posted.

Comment: The only official solution is to wipe your disk and restore a backup. If you don't have a backup, then you'd wipe your disk and run the non-beta installer. You can force the non-beta installer by pressing command+option+R instead of just command+R when going into recovery mode. I'm not saying other approaches won't work, but they're unsupported. https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll

Comment: Yes I did that yesterday morning. All good. Thanks for responding